# bootstrap 3: How to scale a centered image

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML/CSS page that successfully centers an image file in the exact middle  of a Bootstrap 3 page:

```
<head>
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="splash.css" media="screen" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>

<html>

<style>

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    background-color: #D1E5EE;
} 

.container-fluid{
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left: 0

}   

.row-fluid{
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%
}

</style>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row-fluid">
            <div>                
                <img src="images/splash.svg">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

What I'd like  to be able to do is, using CSS, to also have the image in question scale as the browser resizes.

I tried adding something like

```
.splash-image{
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}
```

and then adding a `splash-image` class to the `<img>` tag, but it pushes the image to the right for some reason, and then kind of scales in a hurky-jerky kind of way.

Is there a way to set up the code above so that the image will rescale as the browsre window resizes?

Comment: think your looking for max-width:100%; though im pretty sure thats already defined in the bootstrap framework.. I would probably get rid of the .splash-image aswell if your only looking to have the image scale

Comment: actually I figured it out; I set `img{height: 50%; width: 50%;}` and that did the trick.

Comment: oh and I added `max-height` and `max-width` to the parent div.

Comment: Why don't you use the 'img-responsive' class provided by Bootstrap 3? `<img src="images/splash.svg" class="img-responsive">` and remove the outer `div`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use absolute positioning?
You can use "position: relative" on the body (or the container you want your image to center in) and "position: absolute" with "top: 10%; bottom: 10%; right: 10%; left: 10%".
I'd do something like this:

- HTML:

  ```
  <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <img class="splash-image" src="images/splash.svg">
      </div>
  </body>
  ```
- CSS:

  ```
  body{/* your body style*/}

  .container-fluid {
      /* your container style */
      position: relative;
  }

  .splash-image {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      bottom: 10%;
      left: 10%;
      right: 10%;
  }
  ```